# How to restore pinned message in Telegram super group?

Tags: telegram-messenger

I've mistakenly closed the pinned message for a super group on Telegram I am not an admin of. Is there an easy way to restore the pinned message without the admin having to re-pin?

Seems like this should be easy to do but I can't seem to.

Comment: I've read the admin can unpin and pin it again for it to appear to everyone that closed it. It's worth an issue/feature request on Telegram, however.

Comment: @quimnuss apprently (years later) this is still an issue. There's been an open issue since 2018: https://github.com/telegramdesktop/tdesktop/issues/5526

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah, looks like there is one. You have to

1 - Leave the group
2 - Uninstall Telegram from your phone
3 - Reinstall i.e. download Telegram again from store
4 - Re-join the group

It works on iphone as well as android.

Comment: Bummer, I was hoping for an in-app solution to avoid re-install but that works, thanks for confirming.

Answer (score 0):

First the panic set in with the only solution being the 4 steps, mainly because it's a paid group, so to leave it would be risky depending on the mood of the Admin.

I decided to patiently wait a bit until the next Pinned Post and voila -> SOLVED! Pin Bar is back and so are all the pinned posts.